# How to use NodeJS code in C# win form application

Tags: c#, node.js

I Have developed an application in node JS, working perfectly fine, I have another application written in C# dot net, its Win form application, I want to use the call my NodeJS code inside the winform application.

For example I'll call a function in C# application

`response = CallNodeJsScript(argument1, argument2...);`

Is there any way to do so ?

Can Electron be an option to do so ?

Please help, Thanks

Comment: Well nodeJS is normally used to make a web application. So perhaps you can make a http request to the node application, which would execute your function and return the response? I don't know, you didn't make the scenario fully clear really.

Comment: Actually, there is a library in NodeJS, I want to impliment in a way, if anyone opens my desktop based application, that application will create a local server just like Electron, and then do the stuff

Comment: That's a bit overkill really. Exactly what does this node function do? How complex is it? Could you not just re-write it in c#?

Comment: C# application does not consume JavaScript library. Like the others commented, you either expose your JavaScript functions via REST API or a console app, and then the C# app can call it. It is also possible to rewrite everything in C#, as .NET runs much faster than Node.js.

Comment: https://adiwajshing.github.io/Baileys/#baileys---typescriptjavascript-whatsapp-web-api

Comment: this library i want to use in my c# application, without hosting it on any server

Answer (score 0):

i do not know about elcotron but you can do smt like this:

```js
let handler = {}
handler.mult = function (num1, num2) {
    return num1 * num2
}

const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer(conn => {
    console.log('new client');

    conn.on('data', data => {
        let text = data.toString('utf8')
        let json = JSON.parse(text)
        let func_name = json.name 
        let res = handler[func_name].apply(json.args)
        conn.write(res)
    });

    conn.on('end', () => {
        console.log('client left'); 
    });
});

server.listen(9090);
```

With this you can in your c# make a tcp to 127.0.0.1:9090 and send a json of the format:

```json
{
   name:"mult",
   args:[2,5]
}
```

You do have to add all of you function you want to use to handler

Comment: Thanks, but how can i start the server 127.0.0.1:9090 from c# ?